How do I change the gravity when the Enter key is pressed
So I made a little matter.js thing, using javascript and html, it just creates a black floor, where which a rectangle, trapezoid, square, and circle fall on it:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Include the local Matter.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js" integrity="sha512-rsntMCBgWYEWKl4HtqWmQ3vdHgvSq8CTtJd19YL7lCtKokLPWt7UEoHVabK1uiNfUdaLit8O090no5BZjcz+bw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        // module aliases
        let Engine = Matter.Engine,
            Render = Matter.Render,
            Runner = Matter.Runner,
            Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
            Composite = Matter.Composite;

        // create an engine
        let engine = Engine.create();
        engine.world.gravity.y = 1;

        function changeGravity()
        {
            engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
        }



        // create a renderer
        let render = Render.create({
            element: document.body,
            engine: engine,
            
            options: {
                wireframes: false,
                background: ''
            }
        });

        let RenderOption = {
            isStatic: false,
            render:{
                fillStyle: 'black',
                strokeStyle: 'red',
                lineWidth: 5
            }
        }

        // create two boxes and a ground
        let boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 10, 100, 200, RenderOption);
        let boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80, RenderOption);
        let circle2 = Bodies.circle(500, 40, 50, RenderOption);
        let ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 900, 90, {
            isStatic: true,
            render:{
                fillStyle: 'black'
            }
        });
        let trapezoid = Bodies.trapezoid(400, 60, 100, 100, 0.9, RenderOption);

        // add all of the bodies to the world
        Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground, circle2, trapezoid]);
        
        // Event listener for keydown event
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        changeGravity();
    }
})
        

        // run the renderer
        Render.run(render);
        
        // create runner
        let runner = Runner.create();

        // run the engine
        Runner.run(runner, engine);

        console.log("Engine created:", engine);
        console.log("Render started:", render);
        console.log("Bodies added:", boxA, boxB, ground);
        

    </script>
</body>
</html>



It is supposed to make the gravity 0 when the enter key is pressed.
No matter what I tried this does not work. The wierd thing if I put something like alert() or console.log everything works fine. I cant seem to find the issue.
Thanks.

This works fine for me, running your snippet here in Firefox. When I press Enter, objects no longer fall.

Turns out that my keyboard was glitched.....
Sorry for the confusion!

I believe you do not need to call a function for your event listener.
For my solution, I replaced this:
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        changeGravity();
    }
})

With this:
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
        engine.world.gravity.y = 0
        console.log(engine.world.gravity.y)
    }
})

That way, it should work.

What difference does this make logically? You've simply inlined a function without changing its behavior, so if OP has a bug, it's still there.

Well, I tried the solution, and it changed it to 0. If it works, it works, You can try it out yourself :3

Sure, this works, but OP's code works too. This answer claims that a purely cosmetic refactor fixes something that isn't broken in the first place. The correct action is to comment (which you can do at 50 rep) and ask for clarification.

Well, regardless, he claimed it was broken, so i took their word.

I wouldn't do that--I'd ask them what they meant instead of misleading them by shuffling the code around and pretending like it's a fix. Maybe they thought setting gravity to 0 did something other than it really does, or didn't see that the gravity wasn't gone since the objects had already settled. In this case, to help OP, one needs to follow up and figure out what behavior they're expecting. In any case, since this doesn't change the behavior of OP's code, it doesn't answer the question either way and just throws up a smoke screen.

Will consider that for next time :3
